# Fiware Orion context broker subscription notification issue

Tags: notifications, subscription, fiware, fiware-orion, broker

I'm using orion context broker GE image orion-psb-image-R5.4 version 1.7.0 and I registered a device entity  in it , then i implemented in my raspberry pi simple python server script that listens to any incoming message and print it on the Pi's logs . then i sent a subscription message to the context broker to let my raspberry pi subscribe to its corresponding entity in the context broker. The issue is that whenever i update the condition attributes in the entity in the context broker , they're supposed to trigger a notification to the raspberry pi and then the server script in the PI print the notification in the Pi's logs . But what really happens is that the context broker may trigger the notification for several times and then suddenly stops sending any notification when any additional change is applied to the condition attribute ,  and on every attempt i make i retrieve the subscription status in the context broker and i find that there was a failure stated by the lastfailure attribute giving me the time of my last failed attempt.
I thought the problem could be the connection to my Pi or even in the server script itself but when i launched direct requests from my terminal  to the raspberry pi , it prints the all messages immediately even when the update is made from a remote place . So i concluded that the problem is definitely with the context broker and the notification process of the subscription  itself .

Here's the subscription request i made :

```
curl -v contextbrokeraddress:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header "Fiware-Service: XYZ" --header "Fiware-ServicePath: /XYZ" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": " Try",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Controller1",
        "type": "Controller"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "switch",
        "datashow"

      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://raspberryPiaddress:8080"
    },
    "attrs": [
     "switch",
     "datashow"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

now when the switch attribute is updated with a different value , it may trigger the notification to the raspberry pi for the first time only but then fails on any following attempts.

this is the simple python script that listens to the incoming notifications and print it in its logs:

```
import socket

HOST, PORT = '', 8080

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)

while True:

    print "listening on port 8080"

    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    print "notified"
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print request 
    client_connection.close()
```

And this is how the notification from the context broker is printed on the Pi's logs in its successful times:

```
listening on port 8080
notified
POST / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: orion/1.7.0 libcurl/7.19.7
Host: raspberryPiaddress:8080
fiware-service: XYZ
Fiware-ServicePath: /XYZ
X-Auth-Token: token
Accept: application/json
Content-length: 208
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Fiware-Correlator: f48ced60-1069-11e7-b743-fa163e7c4daf
Ngsiv2-AttrsFormat: normalized

{"subscriptionId":"58cd49191e9c000de6ea89c7","data":[{"id":"Controller1","type":"Controller","switch":{"type":"command","value":"OFF","metadata":{}},"datashow":{"type":"string","value":"OFF","metadata":{}}}]}
```

And when the notification is not received on any following updates on the entity , i check that it was failure by retrieving the subscription status which states that a failure happened in the context broker on sending the notification at the exact time of my attempt. This the status i retrieve to check that:

```
[
    {
        "description": " Try",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "id": "58cd49191e9c000de6ea89c7",
        "notification": {
            "attrs": [
                "switch",
                "datashow"
            ],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://ahmadpi.ddns.net:8080"
            },
            **"lastFailure": "2017-03-24T08:22:23.00Z",**
            "lastNotification": "2017-03-24T08:22:18.00Z",
            "lastSuccess": "2017-03-23T22:09:33.00Z",
            "timesSent": 66
        },
        "status": "failed",
        "subject": {
            "condition": {
                "attrs": [
                    "switch",
                    "datashow"
                ]
            },
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "Controller1",
                    "type": "Controller"
                }
            ]
        },
        "throttling": 5
    }
]
```

the problem now seems to be relating to the context broker and the way the subscription/notification processes are handled inside it . Now, i want to know whether the problem regards the context broker  image version that i used or whether it regards something else . I just want to know where's the problem and how it can be handled please and thanks so much.

Comment: Is there any log trace in the Context Broker log file (typically at `/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log`) as a consequence of the entity update? In that case, please edit your question post to include them. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, please edit your question post in order to state how much time passes between each update attemp. Given that your subscription has a throttling of 5 seconds, that information is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: the notifications could be triggered for once or several times but then suddenly the context broker fails sending additional notifications. what i've observed so far is that the context broker probably fails when i update the condition attribute before the throttling time passes such that the context broker fails completely in that case and i need to restart my server to accept notifications again . could the context broker fail due to this attitude @fgalan  ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, because the case you describe in the last comment doesn't correspond to the one in the question post. I mean, in the question post you mention that "it may trigger the notification to the raspberry pi for the first time only but then fails on any following attempts [updating attribute value]". I mean, nothing about updating condition attribute is said. Pls, review your question post and edit to adjust to the situation that is actually happening, including all the needed information (eg. subscription update request, log traces when attribute is updated, etc.)

Comment: In addition, please include in your question post the Context Broker version you are using. Note that the version of the image (R5.4) is not enough, as Context Broker could have been updated after image deployment. Running `contextBroker --version` will provide the version.

Comment: You're right, actually the situation has slightly changed and i'll update it in the post. I was using NOIP DDNS service that lets my  PI update my router's dynamic address periodically to the DDNS server with a given fixed hostname for the PI and that was the case in which the Orion doesn't send the notification or send it only once. But when i used static ip for the PI, several notifications where received on any update but also stop suddenly, First i thought it might be due to updating the condition attribute so fast but this is not a strong reason. This is clearly my current situation .

Comment: and by the way i used Orion version 1.7.0 .  Perhaps the Orion couldn't resolve the IP address properly in the first case using the DDNS service but  i see that a small change happened in the second case When i gave the router connected to the PI a static IP and the PI accepted successive notifications unlike before and i thought it began to work well , but also suddenly stopped and failures occurred in the Orion. So what do you think about that ?

Comment: Let's try to remove entropy in the setup in order to find the cause of the problem. Please, repeat your test *without* using DNS names, i.e. the raq IP in the http.url field and see what's happen.

Comment: Excuse me , but what do you mean by entropy and where can i find it exactly in the context broker in order to remove it ?

Comment: Let's try to remove entropy = Let's try to make things easier :)

Comment: In sum: please, repeat your test without using DNS names, i.e. the raw IP in the http.url field and see what's happen.

Comment: I've already tried putting the Ip directly in the url field and the PI accepted successive notifications from the context broker and it worked well as i said but sometimes stops for some reason . Now, if i want to use the DNS service how shall i do that , and i want to know if there was a reliable dyndns service to use .

Comment: I'm not sure what could be happening but by "it worked well as I said but sometimes stops for some reasons" I tend to think is some networking/connectivity problem, not directly related with Orion Context Broker. Anyway, as a I suggest in a previous comment, could you have a look to the logs at (typically at `/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log`) when notification fails, please? Edit the question log to add the logs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not fully sure as don't have all the inputs (specially, CB log traces), by *"it worked well as I said but sometimes stops for some reasons"* (see comments thread in the question post) I tend to think is some networking/connectivity problem, not directly related with Orion Context Broker.